# Songs package does not generate PDF booksmarks with lua/xelatex

Tags: songs

The following MWE produces PDF bookmarks for the each `\beginsong`
when compiled with pdflatex, but not when compiled with lua/xelatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{} 
\beginsong{My Song}
\beginverse
\lipsum[1]
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Section 11.6.3 of the manual "PDF Bookmarks and Links" states

> Each \beginsong environment adds a PDF bookmark (if generating a PDF)

...and offers snippets for customizing this behavior. If the equivalent
of the default snippet is included in the premable, xelatex does generate the pdf bookmarks. My guess is that the reference above to "if generating a PDF"
translates into some check that depends on pdflatex specifically, and fails when using other engines.

Here's the working, modified, MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}

% Required for pdf bookmarks if using xelatex/lualatex instead of pdflatex
\renewcommand{\songtarget}[2]
{\pdfbookmark[#1]{\thesongnum. \songtitle}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\songlink}[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}

\beginsong{My Song}
\beginverse
 \lipsum[1]
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right indeed.  The package detects PDF mode checking if `\pdfoutput` is defined.  In LuaTeX `\pdfoutput` does not exist anymore but has been replaced by `\outputmode`.  In principle it should therefore also work to do [`\newcount\pdfoutput \pdfoutput=1` before `\usepackage{songs}`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9a28acef479bea51e2cf8d08b3351638).

Comment: Ideally the `songs` package should use `ifpdf` to check for PDF mode.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I see @kevin-hamlen, the author, is registered on the site. I hope he'll take notice and queue a fix for a future version.

Comment: Noted.  This fix will be included in version 3.1.